# 3 problems with my webpage. Nav menu with flex-direction not working, embedded videos not working, html form behaving weird

Tags: html, css, navigation, html5-video, selection

Hey everyone so I am hoping you can help me once again. I am having a few issues with my web page I am trying to build right now issue one is I can't get the navbar to work with `flex-direction: row;` at all and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong when I am trying to put it in and I couldn't get it to work. The second thing that is not working right is the three videos in the aside container they are not playing anything it goes to load a video then nothing comes up for them not sure if I have missed a step or something. The last issue I am having is in the main container in the form_elements section for the second last item on the form I am trying to make a drop-down selection for a time in hrs and mins at 30-minute intervals from 10 am-9 pm and that part all seems to work but once I gave the two selection elements labels on each of them for hrs and mins that's when it started behaving weird and jumped up to the top of my form and again I don't know why it's behaving that way. If you guys could help provide insight as to why these things are happening and how to fix them I would really appreciate it.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Assignment 3</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is the assignment 3 web page showcasing what we have learned in COMP1223 the so far.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Assignment 3, HTML5, CSS, flexbox, grid, form, image mapping, position fixed, nav">
    <meta name="author" content="Jessica">
    <link href="test2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sansita+Swashed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <!--Create the navigation menu for the page inside the header-->
        <div class="grid_item" id="grid_nav_container">
            <header class="grid_nav_item" id="nav_menu">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#intro">Introduction</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#aside_container">Hobbies</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#application">Application Form</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#form_elements">Form Elements</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#tutorial">Video Tutorial</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#image_mapping">Image Mapping</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <!--Create the header for the greeting and introduction along with a link to the tutorial video.-->
        <div class="grid_item" id="intro">
            <br>
            <br>
            <h1>Welcome to my assignment 3 web page</h1>
            <p>Hello welcome to my page I hope you enjoy taking a look around and seeing some of the things I have learned this semester put into action. On this page you will see examples of background-image, application forms,HTML5 videos, HTML5 forms
                elements, grid, flexbox, image-mapping and a short tutorial video by me covering..... Click on the link below if you’d like to start with that tutorial on....</p>
            <br>
            <p><a href="#tutorial" id="t_link">Watch the ......tutorial </a></p>
        </div>

        <!--Create an aside to hold my hobbies videos-->
        <aside class="grid_item" id="aside_container">
            <div class="grid_aside_item" id="dogs">
                <h3>My Hobbies</h3>
                <h4>Playing with my dogs</h4>
                <video width="500" height="300" controls>
                <source src="/public_html/labs/assignment/assignment3/videos/VID_20180423_185827.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Video of me playing with my dog. Your browser does not support the video tag    
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_aside_item" id="snowboarding">
                <br>
                <h4>Snowboarding</h4>
                <video width="500" height="300" controls>
                <source src="/public_html/labs/assignment/assignment3/videos/pexels-justin-l-5526230.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Video of snowboarding. Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_aside_item" id="gaming">
                <br>
                <h4>Gaming</h4>
                <video width="500" height="300" controls>
                <source src="/public_html/labs/assignment/assignment3/videos/production ID_4151217.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Video of someone gaming. Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- Use main as a 2nd grid container for the application form and form element grid cells-->
        <main class="grid_item" id="main_container">
            <!--Create section containing application form-->
            <section class="grid-main-item" id="application">
                <form method="get">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Application Form</legend>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="fname">Full Name:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="40" required></td>>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="email">Email:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email" size="30" required></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="gender">Gender:</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male
                                    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
                                    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="other">Other
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="skills">Skills:</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="skills" name="skills" value="bash">BASH
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="skills" name="skills" value="html&css">HTML&CSS
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="skills" name="skills" value="c++">C++
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="skills" name="skills" value="javascript">JavaScript
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="post">Post Applying For:</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" id="post" name="post" value="jrdeveloper" required>Jr.Developer
                                    <input type="radio" id="post" name="post" value="softwaredeveloper" required>Software Developer
                                    <input type="radio" id="post" name="post" value="teamleader" required>Team Leader
                                    <input type="radio" id="post" name="post" value="projectmanager" required>Project Manager
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="résumé">Upload Résumé:</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="file" id="résumé" name="résumé" accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="type_résumé">Paste Your Résumé</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id="type_résumé" name="type_résumé" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="notify_me"></label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="notify_me" id="notify_me" value="notify">Notify me of status via email
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="terms"></label></th>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="terms" id="terms" value="terms" required>I agree to the terms & conditions</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></td>
                                <td><button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </section>

            <!--Create a section to contain form elements -->
            <section class="grid_main_item" id="form_elements">
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>HTML5 Form Elements</legend>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="title">Title:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="text" list="titles" size="42" required placeholder="Please select an option or enter your own." />
                                    <datalist id="titles">
                                      <option>Mr.</option>
                                      <option>Mrs.</option>
                                      <option>Miss</option>
                                      <option>Sir</option>
                                    </datalist>
                                </td>
                                <th class="req">*</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="name">Name:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" required pattern="[A-Za-Z]{40}" placeholder="John Doe" </td>
                                    <th class="req">*</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="tel">Phone Number:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" pattern="[0-9]" placeholder="647-123-4156"></td>
                                <th>(optional)</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="email">Email:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="25" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="website">Your Website:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="url" name="website" id="website" pattern="https?://.+" placeholder="https://www.example.com"></td>
                                <th>(optional)</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="nr_items">Nr. of items to order</label></th>
                                <td><select name="nr_items" id="nr_items" required>
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                    <option>5</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                    <option>10</option>
                                </select>
                                </td>
                                <th class="req">*</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="length">Length</label></th>
                                <td><input type="range" name="length" id="length" min="0" max="100" step="10" required></td>
                                <th class="req">*</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="delivdate">Delivery Date</label></th>
                                <td><input type="date" name="delivdate" id="delivdate" min="2020-12-16"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="delivtime">Choose A Delivery Time:</label></th>
                                <label for="hr">hr</label>
                                <select name="delivtime" id="hr">
                                    <option>10</option>
                                    <option>11</option>
                                    <option>12</option>
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                    <option>5</option>
                                    <option>6</option>
                                    <option>7</option>
                                    <option>8</option>
                                    <option>9</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="minute">min</label>
                                <select name="delivtime" id="min">
                                    <option>30</option>
                                    <option>00</option>
                                </select>
                                <th>Delivery window 10am-9pm</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="itemcolour">Item Colour:</label></th>
                                <td><input type="color" name="itemcolour" id="itemcolour" value="#FF0000" </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </section>
        </main>

        <article class="grid_item" id="tutorial">
            <h3>Flexbox 5 Minute Tutorial</h3>
            <iframe src="" height="300" width="500" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
        </article>


        <footer class="grid_item" id="image_mapping">

            <img src="C:/Users/jessi/Desktop/images/youtuber-2838945_1920.jpg" alt="Home desk" usemap="#imgmap">

            <map name="imgmap">
                <area shape="rect" coords="566,204,1262,884" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer">
                <area shape="circle" coords="170,432,70" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens">
                <area shape="circle" coords="418,258,72" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1346,686,1570,892" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1360,452,1681,638" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pouch">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1856,648,1832,924" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen">
                <area shape="rect" coords="1634,648,1832,924" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper">
                <area shape="circle" coords="1446,258,106" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant">
                <area shape="poly" coords="138,7336,376,516,410,544,200,746,478,668,546,906,474,948,242,1020,158,762" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard">
            </map>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "navc navc navc" "int int int" "as . ." "as ar ma" ". . ma" "im im im";
    grid-template-rows: 150px, repeat(5, 500px);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}




#intro {
    font-size: 185%;
    grid-area: int;
    background-image: url('C:/Users/jessi/Desktop/images/coding-1841550_1920.jpg');
    color: #BFFCF9;
    margin: 0px;
    ;
    text-align: center;
}

#tutorial {
    grid-area: ar;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF3FA;
    border-radius: 75px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#image_mapping {
    grid-area: im;
}




#main_container {
    grid-area: ma;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "app" "frm";
    grid-template-rows: 500px 500px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    text-align: center;

}

#application {
    grid-area: app;
    font-size: 90%;
    background-color: #D3FBD8;
    border-radius: 75px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#form_elements {
    grid-area: frm;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: #ED5E93;
    border-radius: 75px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#aside_container {
    grid-area: as;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "dog" "snwbrd" "gmng";
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 500px);
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    text-align: center;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
}

#dogs {
    grid-area: dog;
    background-color: #ED5E93;
    border-radius: 75px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr;
}

#snowboarding {
    grid-area: snwbrd;
    background-color: #D3FBD8;
    border-radius: 75px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr;
}

#gaming {
    grid-area: gmng;
    background-color: #ED5E93;
    border-radius: 75px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr;
}

#req {
    color: #ff0000;
}

#grid_nav_container {
    grid-area: navc;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 150px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav";
}

#nav_menu {
    grid-area: nav;
    background-color: #00C9C8;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 75px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr;
    display:flex
}

#nav_menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Sicne your account is more then 3 years old, you should already know to focus on oen question per question only.

Comment: Sorry account is old but only been actively posting for the past few months while I have been in school. I tried to teach myself how to code and everything but could never find enough time to focus on it now I am in school and it's what I'm doing most every day so I have been posting here a lot more with questions. I didn't think about the one question limit won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

See this example from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) works:

```
<video controls
    src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4"
    poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/title_anouncement.jpg?x11217"
    width="620">

Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos, 
but don't worry, you can <a href="https://archive.org/details/BigBuckBunny_124">download it</a> 
and watch it with your favorite video player!

</video>
```

If you see a message like **"*No video found with compatible format and MIME*"**
the problem is not your code it is your server that does not return the correct mime type or the video file

see [Properly configuring server MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Configuring_server_MIME_types)

Comment: No i dont get that error. And the above example didn't work I moved the src from inside `<source>` to inside `<video>` just like they have it above and nothing. I get a loading wheel at the beginning then it's just black and the controls are not selectable.

Comment: can give me a link to this website page? to see

Comment: I don't have it running on a server yet. Have to upload it to my school when I finish it. But that server requires login info

Comment: verify that the mp4 file exists and that it can be accessed by the browser then check that the server returns the correct mime type